# Visual Studio Compilation errors in V21.1

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development

I have successfully downloaded the source for Bitcoin Nodes V19 and V20 and built them in Visual Studio but get compilation errors when trying to do the same with V21.1. I have reloaded all dependent software packages (Boost etc) using vcpkg, reinstalled Visual Studio, redone vcpkg integrate install but it makes no difference. I am still able to compile and link V20 but not V21.

Is it possible the source code for V21.1 from GitHub is somehow wrong?

Anyone else had this problem?

Thanks,

Jon

Comment: Bitcoin Core's CI infrastructure builds and runs tests with an MSVC build, so presumably the code is fine. It's hard to tell what is wrong without seeing your actual errors.

Comment: I follow https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-windows.md#cross-compilation-for-ubuntu-and-windows-subsystem-for-linux for Windows. Had issues with Visual Studio and never tried again to fix them because WSL is easy and works.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try out updated docs (see https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/22890), and please submit an issue with build errors to https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues.